# Do i need to install both Git and Egit with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am new to github and souce control. i have installed the Egit plugin for eclipse

and i have created the repository on website.

Now i want to ask that do i still need to install GIT installer for windows or not

because then whats the need for Egit.

Also i don't know how can i link the Egit with online Git account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should need Git installed. By installing the Egit plugin you would have a new option to create a Git project from the `File>New Project` if I remember correctly.

Edit: Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html) of how to use the plugin.

Comment: Actually i can't the option (git+ssh) which is shown in this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#github_push and also how can i add my public key . i can't find anything in eclipse. i am on windows

Comment: Try Window>Show View>'something specific to git'. There should be a view for Git and add the repository there.

Comment: i tried that but i am stuck on window where it ask for user and when i clcik next it says authentication failure

Comment: oh, might there be something wrong with the git url you are trying? I remember seeing that before and there was something with my url

Comment: thanks , i had wrong folder for ssh in eclipse preferences . i changed that and now its ok . one thing more i have one more computer to which i want to link this repo. do i need to use same account info or different

Comment: "you should not need Git installed" -- but you probably do, because EGit doesn't implement all features yet, and if you actually try to use git as it's meant to be used, you're going to run into things you can't do, and you'll need the real thing.